# Why does my Visual Studio crashing each time I press a toolbar button?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So I downloaded Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise for Windows 10 for a class. I'm able to code and debug just fine, however if I press any of the toolbar buttons (File, Project, git, tools, etc) VS will freeze for a second, then crash. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried repairing your installation? Sounds like something isn't working as intended.  You can find a guide on how to repair [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I've tried that multiple times, and it didn't help.

Comment: There is a "Report a Problem" feature in VS which you can use to report these kinds of issues. It will attach logs and information that the engineering teams can use to identify what's causing the crash and fix it. If you file a ticket and link to it here, I can take a look for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019